# how to get dutchie graphQL api working with php

Tags: php, api, graphql, graphql-js

I am working to get response from dutchie GrapghQL api using PHP, These are working fine with POSTMAN , but when I am trying to get them work with below Library , its not working at all, and there is very less documentation available for dutchie(php graghql)

https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/

Before I have worked on rest apis with php MySQL, its totally new thing to me so not getting how get it work

[Postman working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwMPy.png)

```
 <?php
 include("library/graphQL/vendor/autoload.php");

 use GraphQL\Client;
 use GraphQL\Exception\QueryError;


 $client = new Client(
'https://plus.dutchie.com/plus/2021-07/graphql',
["Authorization" => "public-  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9."]
 );

// Create the GraphQL mutation
 $gql = (new Mutation('Ping'))
 ->setSelectionSet(
    [
        'id',
        'time',
    ]
);

 // Run query to get results
 try {
$results = $client->runQuery($gql);
 }
 catch (QueryError $exception) {

// Catch query error and desplay error details
print_r($exception->getErrorDetails());
exit;
}

 Display original response from endpoint
 var_dump($results->getResponseObject());

 Display part of the returned results of the object
 var_dump($results->getData()->pokemon);

 Reformat the results to an array and get the results of part of the array
 $results->reformatResults(true);
 print_r($results->getData()['data']);
```

Error I am getting

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mutation' not found in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\dispoapi\index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} 
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dispoapi\index.php on line 21
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to include the class, like this:

```
$gql = (new GraphQL\Mutation('Ping'))
```

Notice the "GraphQL\" in front of "Mutation"? If you don't setup an alias for "Mutation", then that has to be added in front of it.

Otherwise, this has to come after the "GraphQL" library include:

```
use GraphQL\Mutation;
```